# Using Categories with UIResponder - Bad Idea?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm using a Category to add `+load` to `UIResponder`, so that the Cocoapod I'm putting together can get a `didFinishLaunching` notification without the person using the Cocoapod having to modify their `appDelegate`.

**Is this a bad idea?** 
Are there some consequences to doing this that I'm not thinking of?

**Category:**

```c
@implementation UIResponder (MyCategory)

+ (void) load
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: [Observer sharedInstance]
                                             selector: @selector(didFinishLaunching:) name: UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object: nil];
}
@end
```

**Notification Observer:**

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@implementation Observer

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static Observer *bridgeInstance = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (bridgeInstance == nil)
            bridgeInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return bridgeInstance;
}

- (void) didFinishLaunching: (NSNotification*) n
{
    UIWindow *appWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    NSLog( @"application: %@", [UIApplication sharedApplication] );
    NSLog( @"delegate:    %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] );
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categories are for adding methods to types, not overriding methods. Overriding a method with a category is undefined behavior (in some cases it's defined behavior, but may not be the behavior you want). `+load` is an existing method so should never be defined in a category.

This particular situation is really bad because this `+load` may be called numerous times (for every `UIResponder` in the system), so `didFinishLaunching:` may be called any number of times, and you're polluting `NSNotificationCenter` in any case (which has performance implications that could definitely matter at this scale).

You shouldn't do this kind of magic. Let the caller control when your code is run. Even if you wanted to do this kind of magic, it would be better as a `+load` method on `Observer`.